# RxJava 2 Observable Without dependent

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have 2 service that return arraylist :

Observable = api.getCategories();
Observable = api.getProdutcs();

How to execute two service with RxJava?, both service not extended / dependent

When 2 service complete i want to notifyadapter for RV categories and RV products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Observable.zip(api.getCategories()
               ,api.getProdutcs(),
                BiFunction<List<Categories>, List<Product>, Pair<List<Categories>, List<Product>>> { t1, t2 -> Pair(t1, t2) })
  ).subscribeBy{
      it.first//List<Category> update the adapter for category
      ir.second //List<Product> update the adapter for product

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> bro call this method youradapterintance.notifyDataSetChanged();, if you are calling the webservices and setting the adapter in onCreate, then you have to use the event bus , as soon as dataset change then set the adapter on onEventRecieve method.

Answer (score 0):

If your `api.getCategories()` and `api.getProdutcs()` returns different types, you can subscribe second observable after executing first:

```
api.getCategories()
 .subscribe(categories -> api.getProdutcs().subscribe(products -> //Here notify your lists ))
```

Or you can try to use `zip` operator:

```
Observable
    .zip(api.getCategories(), api.getProdutcs(), (categories, products) -> //Here you need to define type of return value )
    .subscribe(yourObject ->//Here notify your lists );
```